# If I return data from a string in php does the string get cleared?

Tags: php, jquery

I have been using jQuery and php for a while, and just wondered something. Say I do a post to php then using a json encode I return data from php. Does the memory that the php was using get cleared.

For instance say in php I put 20,000 characters in a string eg

```
$test['something']="20,000"; //imagine this is a big text line.
echo json_encode($test);
```

Then in jQuery I might have something like

```
$.post("test.php", {},function(data) {
    alert(data.something);
},'JSON');
```

At the point it has returned to jQuery has the php memory been cleared of the 20,000 characters, and anything else I had in any strings?

Comment: Generally speaking it depends what caching methods you're using on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems a bit strange to me!

Essentially because the ordinary way to do the job you're talking about is:

```
$test['something']="20,000"; //imagine this is a big text line.
echo json_encode($test);
exit; // note this additional statement!
```

(or, obviously, without this additional statement if the `echo` is the very last statement of the script)

In other words as soon it echoed the required data the server script stops, so asking if the memory is then cleared or not makes not sense.

So for your question to make sense it might mean that your script keeps active and does something else...? I'm curious about that.
Anyway, in that case, no, the memory is not cleared: `$test` keeps unchanged.

Comment: I have never used the exit; statement before. I just assumed that when the script finished it would free up the memory, and I always assumed this, but I thought I had better ask here, because I am working on something which returns thousands of records, and wanted to be sure.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams So you are in the simple case where your script doesn't do anything else (I edited my answer to be more clear). That's said, I insist: when the script has ended, the question of remaining data has no sense, because _all_ have been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

in general only the data of `test.php` will be cleared.